# Convert a specific time string to datatime pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data with this time format:

```
2021-09-01D00:04:42.305748000
```

How do I read it with pandas? I'm trying it like this:

```
tick_data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(tick_data['timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M")
```

and get this eroor:

```
KeyError: 'timestamp'
```

example of data:

```
timestamp,symbol,side,size,price,tickDirection,trdMatchID,grossValue,homeNotional,foreignNotional
2021-09-01D00:04:42.305748000,AAVEUSDT,Buy,2,391.77,MinusTick,5a2556c8-0662-5f93-2250-f9528c71436b,78354,0.09394082,36.80319
2021-09-01D00:05:12.563305000,AAVEUSDT,Buy,2,394.27,PlusTick,2ff102c5-ae67-1201-9e3c-84ffda41be0d,78854,0.09402915,37.07287
```

Here's how I read them:

```
tick_data = pd.read_csv('trade.csv', names=['timestamp', 'symbol', 'side', 'size', 'price',
                                                      'tickDirection', 'trdMatchID', 'grossValue',
                                                      'homeNotional', 'foreignNotional'], index_col=0, parse_dates=True,
                        low_memory=False)
```

Comment: It appears you don't have a column called `'timestamp'` in your DataFrame

Comment: You may not have a `['timestamp']` column in the dataframe or have not initialized it before

Comment: @EXTERMINATED  update post

Comment: You use `index_col=0` making timestamp your _index_ not a _column_.

Comment: @Henry Ecker   remove those line and get: ValueError: time data 'timestamp' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M' (match)

Comment: Right because it doesn't. Your format string only covers through the minute. `"2021-09-01D00:04"` it doesn't cover the rest of the datetime `":42.305748000"`

Comment: I need chadge it to: "%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%MS" ?

Comment: @henry-ecker Can you tell me which format to use here

Comment: @EXTERMINATED may be u know which format use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) should `usecols` to select from existing columns in csv file, not `names` which will add columns and push column headers into a row in the DataFrame.

```
tick_data = pd.read_csv(
    'trade.csv',
    # Use columns
    usecols=['timestamp', 'symbol', 'side', 'size', 'price',
             'tickDirection', 'trdMatchID', 'grossValue',
             'homeNotional', 'foreignNotional'],
    index_col=0,
    low_memory=False
)
```

`tick_data`:

```
                       timestamp    symbol side  size   price tickDirection                            trdMatchID  grossValue  homeNotional  foreignNotional
0  2021-09-01D00:04:42.305748000  AAVEUSDT  Buy     2  391.77     MinusTick  5a2556c8-0662-5f93-2250-f9528c71436b       78354      0.093941         36.80319
1  2021-09-01D00:05:12.563305000  AAVEUSDT  Buy     2  394.27      PlusTick  2ff102c5-ae67-1201-9e3c-84ffda41be0d       78854      0.094029         37.07287
```

We can then convert the *index* timestamp to datetime with a format string:

```
tick_data.index = pd.to_datetime(
    tick_data.index, format="%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f"
)
```

`tick_data.index`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-09-01 00:04:42.305748', '2021-09-01 00:05:12.563305'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)
```

---

Alternatively, can remove `index_col` to make `'timestamp'` a column:

```
tick_data = pd.read_csv(
    'trade.csv',
    usecols=['timestamp', 'symbol', 'side', 'size', 'price',
             'tickDirection', 'trdMatchID', 'grossValue',
             'homeNotional', 'foreignNotional'],
    low_memory=False
)
tick_data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(
    tick_data['timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f"
)
```

`tick_data.dtypes`:

```
timestamp          datetime64[ns]
symbol                     object
side                       object
size                        int64
price                     float64
tickDirection              object
trdMatchID                 object
grossValue                  int64
homeNotional              float64
foreignNotional           float64
dtype: object
```

`tick_data`:

```
                   timestamp    symbol side  size   price tickDirection                            trdMatchID  grossValue  homeNotional  foreignNotional
0 2021-09-01 00:04:42.305748  AAVEUSDT  Buy     2  391.77     MinusTick  5a2556c8-0662-5f93-2250-f9528c71436b       78354      0.093941         36.80319
1 2021-09-01 00:05:12.563305  AAVEUSDT  Buy     2  394.27      PlusTick  2ff102c5-ae67-1201-9e3c-84ffda41be0d       78854      0.094029         37.07287
```